# Force apply to return a list

Tags: r

I have a matrix and a function that takes a vector and returns a matrix. I want to apply the function to all rows of the matrix and rbind all results together. For example

```
mat <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2)
f <- function (x) cbind(1:sum(x), sum(x):1)
do.call(rbind, apply(mat, 1, f))
```

This works perfectly since the returned matrices have different numbers of rows so apply returns a list. But if they happen to have the same numbers of rows this does not work anymore:

```
mat <- f(3)
apply(mat, 1, f)
```

apply returns a matrix from which I cannot get the result I want. Is it possible to force apply to return a list or is there another solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to split matrix mat before applying function f.

```
list_result <- lapply(split(mat,seq(NROW(mat))),f)
matrix_result <- do.call(rbind,list_result)
```

Comment: This runs into problems when you have to handle empty matrices because seq(0) gives c(1,0).

Answer (score 22):

This is why I love the `plyr` package. It has a number of `--ply` functions that all work in the same way. The first letter corresponds to what you have as input and the second method corresponds to what you have as output (`l` for lists, `a` for arrays, `d` for data frames).

So the `alply()` function works similar to `apply()` but always returns a list:

```
alply(mat, 1, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do lapply across the rows of your matrix:

```
lapply(1:nrow(mat),function(i) f(mat[i,]))
```